# Fetching Customer firstName lastName

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I want to output a list of all orders of all customers, including customers first name and last name. But can't get these two elements.

What I have now is:

```
{% set pastOrders = craft.commerce.orders.find() %}
{% for order in pastOrders %}
    {% for item in order.lineItems %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ craft.commerce.customer.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ craft.commerce.customer.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.options.evenement }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.note }}</td>
      <td>{{order.orderStatus.name}}</td>
      <td>{{ order.datePaid.localeDate() }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

But as you may guess, I've got an error in both fields firstName lastName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all orders will necessarily have a craft user associated with the order.

But all orders must have a billing address, so:

`order.billingAddress.firstName` and `order.billingAddress.lastName` will get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I never used Craft commerce so this answer could be totally wrong but just from looking at the docs the [Order Model](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model#customerid) has the attribute `customerId` and the `customer` attribute that stores the [Customer Model](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/customer-model)

> [customerId](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model#customerid)
>
> The customer record for this order. You can also use customer to get the customer model which can tell you which craft user made the order, as well as access the addresses for this customer.

The `customer model` contains a [user](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/customer-model#user) attribute that stores the default Craft [User Model](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/usermodel) or null

> [user](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/customer-model#user)
>
> Returns a User Model if the customer is logged in, or null if the customer is a guest.

So theoretically you should do something like

```
{% set customer = order.customer %}
{% if customer is not null %}
    {% set user = customer.user %}
    {% if user is not null %}
        {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, I will try your solution. Let you know if this will work.